# Trigger a test on the form of a wordpress widget before submit the Form

Tags: ajax, wordpress, hook

I created a Widget, and I want to perform a Javascript test on the fields of the Form before sending the data.
So I want to know what Hook, wordpress uses on the Submit button.
thank you

Comment: can you post you code?

Comment: this is my Widget Class : [link](http://dro.123.fr/widget.txt).
all code works good, but i juste add a function Javascript when i Click Submit